# Where does println show for an EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster with a bootstrap action that installs a jar file onto the cluster, and I've verified this jar file exists after ssh'ing into the cluster. There is a `System.out.println` statement in that installed jar that I expect to show up after I run an EMR step, but I don't see my statement print anywhere.

I grepped the step's stderr/stdout and the Spark application's container stderr/stdout logs. Does this mean that my expected code in that jar did not run, or can these print statements show up elsewhere?

Comment: They should be visible in driver's logs.